# How to configure spring security saml to authenticate with multiple idp choosen by users

Tags: java, spring-security, saml-2.0, idp, spring-security-saml2

We have an application which uses spring security saml for SSO authentication for a client.
We needed to add a new SSO authentication for our internal users on the login page, so user_client need to click on sso_login_client button to be redirected on its IdP to log in, and user_internal on sso_login_internal button to be redirected on our IdP.

The problem is that our configuration is implemented for only one IdP. What do we need to change to support another IdP ?

Here is our configuration :

SecurityConfig.java

```java
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    @Profile("SSO")
    public static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {
       
        private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);
        private Timer backgroundTaskTimer;
        private MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager;
        
        private String metadataUrl = null;
        private String entityID = null;
        private String entityBaseURL = null;
        private String metadataFile = null;
        private String metadataRetrievalMode = null;
        private Long maxAuthenticationAge = null;
        
    ...
     
        // SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML
        // messages
        @Bean
        public CustomSamlAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider() {
            CustomSamlAuthenticationProvider customSamlAuthenticationProvider = new CustomSamlAuthenticationProvider();
            customSamlAuthenticationProvider.setForcePrincipalAsString(false);
            return customSamlAuthenticationProvider;
        }
     
    ...
        
        // Setup advanced info about metadata
        @Bean
        public ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata() {
                ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
                extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryEnabled(false); 
                extendedMetadata.setSignMetadata(false);
                extendedMetadata.setEcpEnabled(true);
                return extendedMetadata;
        }
        
        
        @Bean
        @Qualifier("idp-adfs")
        public ExtendedMetadataDelegate adfsExtendedMetadataProvider()
                throws MetadataProviderException {
            ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate = null;
            
            if ("FILE".equals(metadataRetrievalMode)) {
                   FilesystemMetadataProvider fileSystemMetadataProvider = new FilesystemMetadataProvider(new File(metadataFile));
                    fileSystemMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
                    
                    extendedMetadataDelegate = new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(fileSystemMetadataProvider, extendedMetadata());
                    extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(false);
                    extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
            } else {
                 String idpKeycloakMetadataURL = metadataUrl;
                 HTTPMetadataProvider httpMetadataProvider = new HTTPMetadataProvider(
                            this.backgroundTaskTimer, httpClient(), idpKeycloakMetadataURL);
                httpMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
                
                extendedMetadataDelegate = new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(httpMetadataProvider, extendedMetadata());
                // Disable metadata trust check to prevent "Signature trust establishment failed for metadata entry" exception
                extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(false);
                extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
            }
            
            backgroundTaskTimer.purge();
            return extendedMetadataDelegate;
        }

        // IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust
        // is here
        // Do no forget to call iniitalize method on providers
        @Bean
        @Qualifier("metadata")
        public CachingMetadataManager metadata() throws MetadataProviderException {
            
              List<MetadataProvider> providers = new ArrayList<MetadataProvider>();
                providers.add(adfsExtendedMetadataProvider());
                CachingMetadataManager metadataManager=new CachingMetadataManager(providers);
                metadataManager.setDefaultIDP(metadataUrl);
                return new CachingMetadataManager(providers);
        }
     
        // Filter automatically generates default SP metadata
        @Bean
        public MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator() {
            MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
            metadataGenerator.setEntityId(entityID);
            if (entityBaseURL != null) {
                metadataGenerator.setEntityBaseURL(entityBaseURL);
            }
            metadataGenerator.setExtendedMetadata(extendedMetadata());
            metadataGenerator.setIncludeDiscoveryExtension(false);
            metadataGenerator.setKeyManager(keyManager()); 
            metadataGenerator.setRequestSigned(false);
            return metadataGenerator;
        }
     

    ...
         
        @Bean
        public SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
            SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter = new SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter();
            samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
            samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
            samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
            return samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter;
        }
        
        // Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages
        @Bean
        public SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
            SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter = new CustomSamlProcessingFilter();
            samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
            samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
            samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
            return samlWebSSOProcessingFilter;
        }
         
        @Bean
        public MetadataGeneratorFilter metadataGeneratorFilter() {
            return new MetadataGeneratorFilter(metadataGenerator());
        }
    
        @Override  
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http
                .httpBasic()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());      
            http
                    .addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                    .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(),BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .addFilterBefore(samlFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
            http .requestMatchers()        
                .antMatchers("/loginSSO/**","/saml/**").and().authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
            http
                    .logout()
                    .disable(); // The logout procedure is already handled by SAML filters.
            
        }
     
        
        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                .authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider());
        }
        
    }
}
```

LoginSSOController.java

```java
@Controller
public class LoginSSOController {
    
    // Logger
        private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginSSOController.class);

        @RequestMapping(value = "/loginSSO", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public View idpSelection(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (auth == null) {
                logger.debug("Current authentication instance from security context is null");
            }else {
                logger.debug("Current authentication instance from security context: ");
            }
            if (auth == null) {
                RedirectView redirect = new RedirectView("/login");
                redirect.setExposeModelAttributes(false);
                return redirect;
            }
            RedirectView redirect = new RedirectView("/dashboard");
            redirect.setExposeModelAttributes(false);
            return redirect;
        }
}
```

login.html

```html
<a href="/loginSSO" class="logAD btn"><i class="fa fa-windows">
    </i> <span th:text="${loginPageSSOLabel}">Login with SSO</span>
</a>
```

I heard about RelyingPartyRegistration but i don't know if it's the right solution for our configuration and how to implement it.

Also i am wondering how does spring-security distinguish multiple IdPs for different users ? Do we need to create a new endpoint like "/loginSSO" ?

Thank you for your help in advance.